# Is getting a downvote really an achievement?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, notifications, achievements-dialog

I just saw that my "Achievements" notification bar showed that I had got two downvotes for my two questions.

How does getting downvotes become an achievement? In my opinion, getting downvotes doesn't classify as achievement unless there is a badge for getting downvotes.

Can it be modified into a more generic term like "Reputation Tracker" or something like that?

Comment: The tool-tip is:

_"Recent achievements: reputation, badges and privileges earned"_. I guess this is a negative achievement.

Comment: @Ben google says Achievement is *a thing done successfully with effort, skill, or courage.* I don't think there can be negative achievement or am I wrong?

Comment: Achievement get: You received _(insert number here)_ downvotes on your meta post.

Comment: I like questions that stir the pot.  +1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The achievements box won't light up if you *only* received downvotes.

You received *other* achievements, and the change in reputation includes the downvotes to explain why you only got `+8` or other such reputation changes.

Comment: I know that you can also receive an achievement (badge) for deleting a question with down votes. It's called peer pressure and you receive this when you delete your own post with a score of -3 or lower.

Comment: @MadsterMaddness: but the *badge* is the achievement.

Comment: @Martin Pieters You are correct, thank you for clarifying that. :)